# String comparison in the core language

Tags: optimization, go

Taking this simple comparison `loopValue == "Firstname"`, is the following statement true?

> If the internal operand inspecting the first `char` does not match the compared string, it will early abort

So taking the rawer form `loopValue` and `"Firstname"` are both `[]byte`. And it would *walk* the array kind of like so as callback loop for truth:

```
someInspectionFunc(loopValue, "Firstname", func(charA, charB) {
    return charA == charB
})
```

... making it keep on going until it bumps `false` and checks if the number of `iterations` was equal to both their lengths. Also does it check length first?

```
if len(loopValue) != len("Firstname") {
    return false
}
```

I can't really find an explanation in the `go` source-code on GitHub as it's a bit above me.

The reason I'm asking this is because I'm doing big data processing and am benchmarking and doing cpu, memory and allocation `pprof` to squeeze some more juice out of the process. From that process it kind of made me think how Go (but also just C in general) would do this under the hood. Is this fully on an assembly level or does the comparison already happen in native Go code (kind of like sketched in the snippets above)?

Please let me know if I'm being too vague or if I missed something. Thank you

**Update**

When I did a `firstCharater` match in big strings of `json`, before really comparing I got about `3.7%` benchmarking gain on 100k heavy entries:

```
<some irrelevant inspection code>.. v[0] == firstChar && v == lookFor {
    // Match found when it reaches here
}
```

the code above (especially on long strings) is faster than just going for `v == lookFor`.

Comment: yes, this is done in assembly, by the `runtime·eqstring` function

Comment: Thank your for your response JimB. Do you know how that process goes about the inspection? Does it always fully iterate and/of compare both variable's length or does it early abort when equal index-depth doesn't match anymore?

Comment: no, it always compares length first. there's no reason to iterate if they're not the same length.

Comment: checking the first byte might be a special case optimization for you. I think the default amd64 comparison for large strings will always load 2 64byte chunks into registers to make the first comparison. It's possible that the single byte check is slightly faster. This is in the realm of "very hard to measure", because this all depends so much on the cpu, memory layout, and cache state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is handled in assembly. The amd64 version is:

```
TEXT runtime·eqstring(SB),NOSPLIT,$0-33
    MOVQ    s1str+0(FP), SI
    MOVQ    s2str+16(FP), DI
    CMPQ    SI, DI
    JEQ eq
    MOVQ    s1len+8(FP), BX
    LEAQ    v+32(FP), AX
    JMP runtime·memeqbody(SB)
eq:
    MOVB    $1, v+32(FP)
    RET
```

And it's the compiler's job to ensure that the strings are of equal length before that is called. (The `runtime·memeqbody` function is actually where the optimized memory comparisons happen, but there's probably no need to post the full text here)

The equivalent Go code would be:

```
func eqstring_generic(s1, s2 string) bool {
    if len(s1) != len(s2) {
        return false
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(s1); i++ {
        if s1[i] != s2[i] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: I did NASM on an old Mac years ago. I should really get into that again to be able to debug on this scale too :). I'll up vote this when the cooldown period is over. Thanks so much for collaborating as always JimB!